# update sqlite columns based on other columns information

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to use information from a sqlite db and update another columns with some conditions using Python 3.6

python 3.6 and sqlite

```
def open_days(signed_date,completed_date):
    fmt = '%Y-%m-%d'
    if completed_date == '':
        if signed_date:
            sdate = datetime.strptime(signed_date, fmt)
            tdate = datetime.now() 
            delta = str((tdate - sdate).days)

            return delta

    else:
        sdate = datetime.strptime(signed_date, fmt)
        cdate = datetime.strptime(completed_date, fmt)   
        delta = str((cdate - sdate).days)

        return delta

conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM data_table")
for row in cur:
    cur.execute("UPDATE data_table SET days_open=? WHERE numid=?", (open_days(row[1],row[2]),row[0]))
    cur.fetchall()

cur.close()
conn.commit()
```

I am expecting the result to be:

```
numid,signed_date,completed_date, number_of_days
1234,2019-05-15,,16
2345,2019-04-29,,32
3456,2019-04-29,2019-05-13,14
4567,,,None
```

the value are not udpated with the correct value if the number of days is set manually

```
numid,signed_date,completed_date, number_of_days
1234,2019-05-15,,16
2345,2019-04-29,,16
3456,2019-04-29,2019-05-13,16
4567,,,16
```

Note that it can be that no signed date and no completed date is already register into the db as per example showing some blank space between coma.

if signed date and completed date are registered then the number of day is the difference between completed date and signed date

if only signed date is registered then number of day is the difference between today's date and signed date

if no signed date then number of day is None

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to update the rows:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
conn.create_function('open_days', 2 , open_days)
cur = conn.cursor()

for row in cur.execute('SELECT signed_date, completed_date, open_days(signed_date,completed_date) FROM data_table'):
    cur.execute('UPDATE data_table SET days_open=(open_days(signed_date,completed_date))')
cur.close()
conn.commit()
```

change to as per Sam input:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('mydb.db')
conn.create_function('open_days', 2 , open_days)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('UPDATE data_table SET days_open=(open_days(signed_date,completed_date))')
cur.close()
conn.commit()
```

Comment: Can't you take out the loop and the SELECT statement now? The UPDATE statement already updates all rows in the table, so you're repeatedly doing the same update

Comment: yes this is working much better, for some reason this was not working so I removed the for loop and select and only do the UPDATE. many thanks